# Data formatting in oracle 11g using pivot

Tags: oracle, pivot, self-join

I have a table ATTRIBUTES in oracle 11g as

```
order           attribute                            value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
802605          CL_ACC844FIBRE_SERVICE                  N

802605          CL_ACC844FIBRE_SERVICE_LOCATION         N

802605          CL_ACC844FLOOR                          GROUND

802605           CL_ACC844HAZARD                        BTSS  

802605          CL_ACC844HOUSING                        CABINET

802605          CL_ACC844TEAM                           EDINBURGH

802605          CL_ACC844LANDLORDS_CONSENT                Y

802605         CL_ACC844LANDLORDS_NECESSARY                N

802605         CL_ACC844LANDLORD_NAME                   NOT APPLICABLE

802605          CL_ACC844LANDLORD_PHONE                 NOT APPLICABLE

802605          CL_ACC844LOCATION                       ROOM 

802605         CL_ACC844MAINTENANCE_CAT                 FIBRE 

802605         CL_ACC844NTE_CHASSIS                     SINGLE SLOT

802605         CL_ACC844OCCUPANCY_COMMENCE_DATE         17/02/2012
```

And  each order contains hundreds of attributes like this

The format I want the data in is something like this

```
ORDER   TECH  BLEACH  AF1        AF2            AF3         AF4     EF
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
802605   N     YES  11/10/2007  11/10/2007  11/10/2007  11/10/2007  1/10/2007
```

The query I use to get the data is

```
SELECT a1.order ,
       a1.value tech  ,
       a2.value bleach  ,
       a3.value af1  ,
       a4.value af2  ,
       a5.value af3  ,
       a6.value af4  ,
       a7.value ef  
  FROM attributes a1,
       attributes a2,
       attributes a3,
       attributes a4,
       attributes a5,
       attributes a6,
       attributes a7
 WHERE a1.order = '802605-S844'
         AND a1.order = a2.order
         AND ( a1.atribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS_ACCESS_TECHNOLOGY'
         OR a2.atribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_VCG_DETAILS1COS_BLEACHING_FLAG'
         OR a3.atribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_VCG_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF1'
         OR a4.atribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_VCG_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF2'
         OR a5.atribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_VCG_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF3'
         OR a6.atribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_VCG_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF4'
         Or A7.atribute Like 'CL_ACC%G_VCG_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_EF' );
```

I know this is not the right way to format data using self-joins and also I have to get the data for 400 orders so the query takes days to show data. 
Can someone give a better way to format the data. I have tried using PIVOT but was unable to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT order,
       MAX( CASE WHEN attribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS1COS_BLEACHING_FLAG'
                 THEN value END ) AS tech,
       MAX( CASE WHEN attribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF1'
                 THEN value END ) AS bleach,
       MAX( CASE WHEN attribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF2'
                 THEN value END ) AS af1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN attribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF3'
                 THEN value END ) AS af2,
       MAX( CASE WHEN attribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_AF4'
                 THEN value END ) AS af3,
       MAX( CASE WHEN attribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS1G_6LAYER_COS_CIPR_EF'
                 THEN value END ) AS af4,
       MAX( CASE WHEN attribute LIKE 'CL_ACC%G_ADSL_DETAILS_ACCESS_TECHNOLOGY'
                 THEN TO_DATE( value, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) END ) AS ef
FROM   attributes
WHERE  order IN ( '802605-S844' /*, ...*/ )
GROUP BY order;
```

Comment: Bear with my ignorance here, but why is MAX used here ?

Comment: You are grouping by `ORDER` so you need to aggregate all the other columns. The `CASE` statement, hopefully, ensures that only the single correct row in each column generates a non-`NULL` value for that column. Aggregation functions will typically ignore `NULL` values and any aggregation function can be used to get that one non-`NULL` value provided it does not try to do other arithmetic operations. So `MAX` or `MIN` would work interchangeably but `SUM` or `AVG` won't like it if you use them on a string value.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. I was just wondering if same result can be achieved by using Oracle 11g PIVOT.

Comment: Probably, but it is not as simple as the attribute values contain part of the order value (i.e. `844`) which can be easily avoided using `LIKE` and wild-cards using this method but would possibly require taking a sub-string to be able to get a consistent set of attributes to `PIVOT` on across the groups.